# Different behavior of Fragment's onCreateView depending on how it is added to activity

Tags: android

According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#Adding), there are two ways to add a fragment to an activity:

First: declare the fragment inside the activity's layout file.

Second: programmatically add the fragment to an existing ViewGroup.

Only when I try the second way and then make a configuration change like rotation, `onCreateView` is called twice for the first rotation and thrice for the second rotation, and so on.

Why does this cumulative behavior of `onCreateView` occur only when adding the fragment programmatically to activity?

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ExampleFragment exampleFragment = new ExampleFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, exampleFragment)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

ExampleFragment.java

```
public class ExampleFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.e("ExampleFragment", "onCreateView");
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.example_fragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

example_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Is it happening on a real device, if yes please try it on another device or simulator. I have faced similar problem on specific xiaomi devices. Those devices received configuration changes event multiple times thus multiple lifecycle event callback.

Comment: Thanks minhazur for reply. Yes, it's happening on real device. It's Lenovo. I also tried it on simulator, sometimes I get 5 logs for one rotation, sometimes 2 or 3. It's just random on simulator, but I can assure you it's cumulative on my real device.

Comment: Fragments restore themselves automatically, so you're adding more and more copies. You need to surround programmatically added Fragments with `if (savedInstanceState == null)` checks so you only add it once.